# Unix command to search for text string in all files

Tags: macos, bash, unix, find, grep

How do I get unix to search inside ALL files for a the string "hello"?

I've tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
sudo grep "hello" | find / -name "*" 2>/dev/null
```

Does anyone have any other ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Maybe this one?

```
sudo cd / && grep -rn "hello" *
```

EDIT: the 'n' option of course is not needed - it simply displays the line numbers and I find it nice. The 'r' option tells grep to perform recursive search within directories.

Comment: Specifying `.` may be preferable over `*` if there are a lot of files in the directory. (You can hit a too many arguments error)

Comment: @NBenatar thought about this solution but I think this solution is a bit easier to understand. Could be that I am wrong.

Comment: @izomorphius: You have three bugs. First, `cd` will be executed with `sudo` and switch to `/`, but `grep` wont be executed as the `sudo`'d user (IOW, not as root). Second, because `cd /` was in another shell the actual working directory won't change and `grep` will not run in `/` (unless `/` was the working directory already, in which case why `cd`?). Thirdly, `grep -r '' *` will not search all files since `*` will not expand hidden files and directories (those with a leading `.`) unless `shopt -s dotglob` is in effect (`bash` only).

Comment: how would I do this but just search .html files?

Answer (score 11):

Use

```
grep -r 'pattern' /
```

If your `grep` supports `-r`, (GNU `grep` does); if not use

```
find / -type f -exec grep 'pattern' {} +
```

If your `find` supports `-exec` with `+`, otherwise use

```
find / -type f -printf '%p\0' | xargs -0 grep 'pattern'
```

If your `find` supports `-printf` and your `xargs` supports `-0`, or

```
find / -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep 'pattern'
```

If your `find` supports only `-print0` and your `xargs` supports `-0`. In all other cases fall back on

```
find / -type f | xargs grep 'pattern'
```

This is maximally compatible, with the caveat that certain unusual file names will fail to be grepped and crafted file names could pose a security risk.

Note that you will have to be root in order to be sure of searching all files and that the search will be case-sensitive unless you add `-i` to `grep`.

Comment: find / -type f | xargs grep 'pattern' ==> works for aix!

Answer (score 2):

This?

```
find . -exec grep -H "hello" {} \;
```